# what is the purpose of [location.nlc, ...groups] in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am learning typescript and very new about it. At the moment, I am trying to read some projects code so I can understand bit quicker.
I am confused about the usage of `[location.nlc, ...groups]` and const `nlc`. say

`groups=['b','c','d'];
 location.nlc="a";`

Following code will just create a dictionary with same value and key 'a','b','c','d'. Is my guess correct?

```
const groups = location.groups ? location.groups.split(",") : [];
    const clusters: ClusterMap = {};
    for (const nlc of [location.nlc, ...groups]) {
      clusters[nlc] = nlc;
    }
```

Comment: maybe read on the new es6 operators and features?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 1):

Here is an annotated example, there are some neat TypeScript features here:

```
// if the loc.groups has a value, split it by comma (otherwise use an empty array)
const groups = loc.groups ? loc.groups.split(",") : [];

// variable for the cluster map
const clusters: ClusterMap = {};

// for each string (nlc) in the expanded array of loc.nlc (which is 'z'), and all the items in groups (which are a, b, c, d)
for (const nlc of [loc.nlc, ...groups]) {
    // add the item to the cluster map with a key of (for example 'z')
    // and a value of (for exmaple 'z')
    clusters[nlc] = nlc;
}
```

The net result is:

```
{
    z: 'z',
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c',
    d: 'd'
}
```

Coolest feature in the example:

```
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
const arr2 = [4, 5, 6];

// 0,1,2,3,4,5,6
const combined = [0, ...arr1, ...arr2]
```